# Correct SQL syntax when creating multiple tables in one database

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mariadb

sorry for the long-winded question but I really have no idea where I've gone wrong. I am trying to create three tables (Patients, Beds, and Appointments) in a database on 000webhost using the following code:

```
                                                    // PATIENTS
    
    // Create table
    $sql_Patients = "CREATE TABLE $tbl_Patients (
        patientID BIGINT PRIMARY KEY,
        firstName VARCHAR(255),
        lastName VARCHAR(255),
        age INTEGER(255),
        isMale BOOLEAN,
        diagnosis VARCHAR(255)
    )
    ";

    // Check
    echo "About to execute $sql_Patients";
    if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql_Patients)) {
        echo "Table $tbl_Patients created successfully<br>";
    } else {
        echo "Error creating table: " . mysqli_error($conn) . "<br>";
    }

    // Add data
    $sql_Patients = "INSERT INTO $tbl_Patients 
        VALUES (123123123123,'John','Doe',30,1,'Sore throat')
    ";

    // Check
    if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql_Patients)) {
        echo "New records created successfully<br>";
    } else {
        echo "Error: " . $sql_Patients . "<br>" . mysqli_error($conn);
    }

    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    
                                                    // BEDS
    
    // Create table
    $sql_Beds = "CREATE TABLE $tbl_Beds (
        bedID INTEGER(255) PRIMARY KEY,
        size VARCHAR(255),
    )
    ";

    // Check
    echo "About to execute $sql_Beds";
    if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql_Beds)) {
        echo "Table $tbl_Beds created successfully<br>";
    } else {
        echo "Error creating table: " . mysqli_error($conn) . "<br>";
    }

    // Add data
    $sql_Beds = "INSERT INTO $tbl_Beds
        VALUES (1,'M')
    ";

    // Check
    if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql_Beds)) {
        echo "New records created successfully<br>";
    } else {
        echo "Error: " . $sql_Beds . "<br>" . mysqli_error($conn);
    }
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    
                                                    // APPOINTMENTS
    
    // Create table
    $sql_Beds = "CREATE TABLE $tbl_Appointments (
        time TIME PRIMARY KEY,
        duration INTEGER(255),
    )
    ";

    // Check
    echo "About to execute $tbl_Appointments";
    if (mysqli_query($conn, $tbl_Appointments)) {
        echo "Table $tbl_Appointments created successfully<br>";
    } else {
        echo "Error creating table: " . mysqli_error($conn) . "<br>";
    }

    // Add data
    $sql_Beds = "INSERT INTO $tbl_Appointments
        VALUES ('08:00:00','30')
    ";

    // Check
    if (mysqli_query($conn, $tbl_Appointments)) {
        echo "New records created successfully<br>";
    } else {
        echo "Error: " . $tbl_Appointments . "<br>" . mysqli_error($conn);
    }
```

However, this is what I see when I run the code on my web server database:
[image: Snippet]

Please advise. Thank you!

Comment: spare comma after size VARCHAR(255) voting to close as typo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The statement to create `$tbl_Beds` fails because it has a trailing comma after the last column definition (size):

```
// Create table
$sql_Beds = "CREATE TABLE $tbl_Beds (
    bedID INTEGER(255) PRIMARY KEY,
    size VARCHAR(255)
)"
# Comma removed here ^;
```

The following `insert` then fails because the table was not created.

The creation of `$tbl_Appointments` then due to a similar mistake:

```
// Create table
$sql_Beds = "CREATE TABLE $tbl_Appointments (
    time TIME PRIMARY KEY,
    duration INTEGER(255)
)";
# Comma removed here ----^;
```

And the following `insert` to it also fails because the table does not exist.